# Carrierwave precalculated md5 checksum of a file as a filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

Using carrierwave uploader for images, trying to provide uniqueness of uploaded images using md5 checksum as filename

looks like I'm doing something wrong

model is defined like:

```rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :img
  mount_uploader :img, ImageUploader
```

My uploader code is as following:

```rb
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
storage :file

def store_dir
  "images/#{filename[0,2]}"
end

def md5
  @md5 ||= ::Digest::MD5.file(current_path).hexdigest
end

def filename
  @name ||= "#{md5}#{::File.extname(current_path)}" if super
end
```

first of all, I suspect this approach inflicts calculation of checksum each time image entry is queried to display

secondly, after image entry is saved, every other of `img.original_filename` `img.filename` `img.path` `img.current_path` seem to be undefined with following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:17:in `store_dir'
carrierwave (0.5.7) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:43:in `store_path'
carrierwave (0.5.7) lib/carrierwave/storage/file.rb:41:in `retrieve!'
carrierwave (0.5.7) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:95:in `block in retrieve_from_store!'
carrierwave (0.5.7) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.5.7) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:94:in `retrieve_from_store!'
carrierwave (0.5.7) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:311:in `uploader'
```

any kind of help or tip is appreciated

**UPD:**

changed uploader this way:

```rb
def store_dir
  "images/#{model.img_identifier[0,2]}"
end

def filename
  @name ||= "#{md5}#{::File.extname(current_path)}"
end

protected
def md5
  var = :"@#{mounted_as}_md5"
  model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, ::Digest::MD5.file(current_path).hexdigest)
end
```

`current_path` seems to refer to full path of form-submitted tempfile, thus being valid for extension extraction and digest calculation
`img_identifier` stands for persisting resulting filename and thus goes valid for prefix extraction for our `store_dir`
still not sure if any caveat is induced with this approach

also still not convinced about the way file uniqueness validation should be performed

**UPD:**

I've added this `before_validation` callback in my model class:

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :checksum
before_validation :assign_checksum

def assign_checksum
  self.checksum = img.md5 if img.present? and img_changed?
end
```

where `checksum` is a separate string field in my model's db table
it **is** quite redundant as it duplicates the `img` field in general, but I still can't figure out the way to validate uniqueness of `img` itself.

**UPD:**

Moved away from db redundancy this way. In my model:

```rb
validate :img_uniqueness

def img_uniqueness
  errors.add :img, "Image already exists in database" if Image.where(:img => self.img.filename).first
end
```

now there's no need in `checksum` field

Comment: Love the idea! You might also think about using SHA1 sum for this.

Comment: whenever `filename` is called on a new instance of ImageUploader, the MD5 sum is calculated.

Comment: `img.original_filename` refers to the filename on the remote client, e.g. that's what the user called the file before on their disk, before they uploaded it.. -- e.g. that should not change / be changed

Comment: updated with solution. I've chosen MD5 over SHA1 because it's about 2 times faster

Comment: File uniqueness: see bottom of my answer

Answer (score 3):

This could help:
How to: Use file`s MD5 as filename
[https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-file%60s-MD5-as-filename](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Use-file%60s-MD5-as-filename)

And maybe

How-to: Use file's digest (e.g. MD5, SHA-1) as file path
[https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-file's-digest-(e.g.-MD5,-SHA-1)-as-file-path](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Use-file%27s-digest-%28e.g.-MD5,-SHA-1%29-as-file-path)

Answer (score 1):

Add a md5hash field to your model, then add the following code to your Model:

```
  before_validation :compute_hash
  validates_uniqueness_of :md5hash, :on => :create

  def compute_hash
    self.md5hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.file.read)
  end
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**1. When you define `store_dir` .. filename seems to be NIL!!**

That seems to be the immediate error -- **try a `puts` statement to print out what filename is set to..**

If the filename is NIL, you'll see the error you're seeing:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:17:in `store_dir'
```

**NOTE:**

you're overriding **both** filename and store_dir ... and using filename inside the definition of store_dir...
There could be a "chicken and the egg" type of problem here.. better check on that

**store_dir** should just be a directory, e.g. `/somewhere/on/your/disk/images`

**filename** should just be a filename without path, e.g. `24371592d9ea16625854ed68ac4b5846` , or  `24371592d9ea16625854ed68ac4b5846.jpg`

e.g. check how those two are used in the code in `store.rb`  (at end below)

Question:

using `filename[0,2]` - you're using directories with 2-letter prefix of the MD5-sum to store the images?

**2. Side-note: What is `current_path`??** Seems a misnomer. Should be a path+filename, not just a path

**3. Check the second code snippet (below) from `store.rb`**

Seems like you set `store_dir` to a relative directory -- that's very fragile and error prone.. it might be a better idea to set it to an absolute path (starting with '/')

**4. Try setting filename and store_dir to constants for debugging**

Just as a sanity check, does it work when you do this:

```
def store_dir
   '/tmp/'      # from the source code, it looks like this needs to start with '/' !!
end

def filename
   'my_uploaded_file'
end
```

that should work before setting filename to MD5 sum..

---

**From the source code:** (0.5.7)

lib/carrierwave/storage/file.rb

lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb

You can **override CarrierWave::Uploader::Store#filename** to point to a filename of your choice (see source code):

Overriding it in CarrierWave::Uploader::Base should work, as 'Store' is included in 'Base' ; this overrides the default filename.

**From`store.rb`**

```
  # Override this in your Uploader to change the filename.                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  # Be careful using record ids as filenames. If the filename is stored in the database                                                                                                                                                                                      
  # the record id will be nil when the filename is set. Don't use record ids unless you                                                                                                                                                                                      
  # understand this limitation.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  # Do not use the version_name in the filename, as it will prevent versions from being                                                                                                                                                                                      
  # loaded correctly.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  # === Returns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  # [String] a filename                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  def filename
    @filename
  end
```

You could also check for the cached filename, compute the MD5-sum (or **better SHA1 sum**) on it, and then use the result to name the file.

---

**From`store.rb`**

```
  # Calculates the path where the file should be stored. If +for_file+ is given, it will be                                                                                                                                                                                 
  # used as the filename, otherwise +CarrierWave::Uploader#filename+ is assumed.                                                                                                                                                                                            
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  # === Parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  # [for_file (String)] name of the file <optional>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  # === Returns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  # [String] the store path                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  def store_path(for_file=filename)   # DEFAULT argument is filename - you don't need to override both
    File.join([store_dir, full_filename(for_file)].compact)
  end
```

---

File Equality:

```
files_equal?( filename1, filename2 )

      return true if File.size(filename1) == File.size(filename2)

      # return MD5(filename1) == MD5(filename2)

      # as we assume that the filename == MD5 + some suffix :

      return File.basename(filename1) == File.basename(filename2)   # if names == MD5 are the same

end
```

Comment: I use 2 letter prefix directories for better filesystem performance as I consider to store huge number of images and thus it's a common practice to partition files this way. as hinted here https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-a-fast-lookup-able-storage-directory-structure

Comment: I'll elaborate on solution I've found a bit later.

Comment: yes, structuring them in such directories sounds like a good idea

Comment: see the last upd section of my question for uniqueness validation workaround

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the wiki way for file name uniquess,

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

Comment: what's the point of using **random** uuid for image file considering the desire to validate uniqueness based on file contents? found the way to do it myself, I'll elaborate later on that, with a bit of redundancy I apprehend, working for me nevertheless

Comment: md5 checksum is useful to get very different signature for very little  changes ; which allow file intergrity check. md5 collision is always possible, and probality increase with big amount of data. But your right I miss read your answer, I thought you wanted filename uniqueness

Comment: well then collision occurrence may be significantly diminished by moving toward uniqueness validation of file_size-checksum pair